# To get gpu support to create neural networks is conda environment necessary?

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip, pytorch, conda

So I recently started learning about deep learning in the TensorFlow lib in python. And came across a problem, so turns out, (and I genuinely didn't know this) to use the GPU for programming specially TensorFlow and PyTorch you need these CUDA toolkit, cuDNN libs, and Visual Studio community. Which far enough I'll download and already finished downloading vs community. 
But what I want to ask is, is the setting up of Conda environment necessary? Can it not be done with pip?

Sorry if this is not the right place to ask this kind of question, but I couldn't find anything in detail about this.

Comment: If your doubt about GPU support has been solved. Can you accept one of the below answer, to close this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can just use `pip install tensorflow-gpu` to install TensorFlow with GPU support. It's your choice if you want to create Conda environment or not. But before using that pip command, make sure you have CUDA 11.2 and cuDNN 8.1. 
And in case of PyTorch just go to [this](https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/) site and copy the command and install it.

Comment: thanks, so only cuda toolkit cudnn and tensorflow-gpu got it

Comment: No, you also need msvc 2019. And Python version between 3.6 to 3.9 to install the latest TensorFlow i.e. 2.6.0

Answer (score 1):

> Q: is the setting up of conda environment necessary?

No, it isn't. For instance, as you can see [here](https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/), you can install PyTorch using both pip and conda, and other alternatives:

> pip3 install torch torchvision torchaudio

By the way, you do not need to install the CUDA toolkit and cuDNN libs, because they are already shipped in the `.whl` files (at least the CUDA runtime, cuDNN, and NCCL are). You only need to install CUDA-related libs if you're going to compile something. Also, using Visual Studio is optional. You can choose whatever IDE you like (e.g., PyCharm, Sublime, etc.), even none.

Comment: oh thanks, i was following this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=StH5YNrY0mE and he said that conda is necessary and also visual studio too.

Comment: @Berriel: Are you sure that installing CUDA and cuDNN are not necessary for Tenorflow? Can use provide some documents to support it? As [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu#software_requirements) states, tensorflow needs them to support GPU.

Comment: @Kaveh you're correct... it seems they no longer do it. Thanks! I updated the answer.